# Meaning of these logcat messages

Tags: android, android-logcat

I got this error in Log but it doesn't prevent my app from processing and doesn't do any errors in app but i don't what's it

```
01-12 09:54:41.726 14988-15006/com.android.muslimstudios.bookstore W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-12 09:54:41.731 14988-15006/com.android.muslimstudios.bookstore W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe0513980, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-12 09:54:41.908 14988-15006/com.android.muslimstudios.bookstore D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xe03c5a00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xe0dbe390
01-12 09:54:52.360 14988-14998/com.android.muslimstudios.bookstore W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.121ms
```

Answer (score 5):

None of those are errors. `W/` is a warning; `D/` is a debug message.

Pretty much any Android app will trigger those specific messages from time to time. Please ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

If logcat gives you an error message, it will be E/ tag and red text

Answer (score 0):

These are messages from the Android emulator and can be helpful in some situations. If you would like to filter these out, however, I would suggest (per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71209827/16593914)) ***only filtering out the Debug messages***, and not the Warning or Error messages as those may be useful.

Prefix:

- `D/` - Debug
- `W/` - Warning
- `E/` - Error

**For Android Studio Logcat logs**:

- Use the method recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71071810/16593914) in logcat but modify to `^(?!(D/EGL_emulation))` so that Warnings and Errors will still show.

**For VSCode Debug Console logs**:

- Simply use a Filter exclusion string as `!D/EGL_emulation`.

Comment: How would I add this in Android Studio 2020.3.1? No Logcat, just Console, and no "Edit Configurations" for the console